# insertBefore xml php

Tags: php, xml, dom

first time over here :o) ... need your help as this is driving me crazy this far away ... Right..

I have this xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<juiceboxgallery galleryTitle="whatever">
    <image imageURL="images/23.jpg" thumbURL="thumbs/23.jpg" linkURL="images/23.jpg" linkTarget="_blank" sourcePath="webadded"></image>
    <image imageURL="images/24.jpg" thumbURL="thumbs/24.jpg" linkURL="images/24.jpg" linkTarget="_blank" sourcePath="webadded"></image>
    ... and so on ...
</juiceboxgallery>
```

And i want to insert new elements just before de first 'image' on the list...

What's the right way to do it..??

All my tries are resulting inserting just before 'juiceboxgallery' or after the closing tag. No way to put it where i want...

Trying to get the the first image element with getElemtnstByTagName("image")->item(0) and doing an insertBefore($new_donde,$first_node) throws me a Not Found Error!! with this code...

```
$nodo_zero=$doc->getElementsByTagName('image')->item(0);
$doc->insertBefore($nuevo_nodo,$nodo_zero);
```

.. even when cheking that I have 'X' image elements with this:

```
$images=$doc->getElementsByTagName("image");
echo "<hr>imagenes: ".$images->length."<hr>";
```

.. please some help :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods like insertBefore() and appendChild() have to be called on the parent node. The document itself is a node, too. So it has the methods and allows to add multiple nodes, but only a single element node.

In your case, here are to possible approaches.

Use the `DOMNode::parentNode` property

```
$nodo_zero = $doc->getElementsByTagName('image')->item(0);
$nodo_zero->parentNode->insertBefore($nuevo_nodo,$nodo_zero);
```

Or fetch the `juiceboxgallery` node and use the `DOMNode::firstChild` property.

```
$gallery = $doc->getElementsByTagName('juiceboxgallery')->item(0);
$gallery->insertBefore($nuevo_nodo, $gallery->firstChild);
```

Comment: OH! My!!! ... Thanks you so much ThW .. you saved my day!! It's works perfectly ... :o)  .. I tryed the second way and now i get my new images just at the begining!!